# converting datetime string to POSIXct date/time format in R

Tags: string, r, datetime, posixct

Consider a string in the format

```
test <- "YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000-08:00"
```

My goal is to convert those strings to `POSIXct` format so that I can plot the data. my initial thought was to use

```
as.POSIXct(test)
```

...but that seems to truncate the datetime to just date. Any thoughts? The help info for `as.POSIXct` seems to imply that the input should be date and time separated by a space, not by a "T". Is this my issue?

Answer (score 51):

You need to specify a format for your conversion. Take a read of `?strptime` to see all of the options for date formats.

```
#YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000-08:00
test <- "2013-12-25T04:32:16.500-08:00"
z <- as.POSIXct(test,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
op <- options(digits.secs = 3)
z
#[1] "2013-12-25 04:32:16.5 EST"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer here. I have a Question too...`chr [1:10000] "2016-05-30 23:39:51 UTC" "2016-05-30 23:52:34 UTC"` is my data. So i get it to convert with `as.POSIXct`: as.POSIXct(df$event_ts_utc,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS") working fine, except for the TIMECODE `"2016-05-30 23:39:51 CEST"`! Any Ideas?

Comment: did it! `as.POSIXct(df$event_ts_utc,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")`

Comment: I had a slightly differently formatted date time stamp, so for me what worked was: `as.POSIXct("2019-03-15 16:17:42" , format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")`