# R: convert date from character to datetime

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I have `df$date` as character type below:

```
     date
1    "2016-04-10T12:21:25.4278624" 
2    "2016-04-12T10:01:42.9573987" 
3    "2016-04-12T10:02:15.2168753" 
4    "2016-04-12T10:02:45.3005686"
```

I want to convert it to datetime object and tried `as.Date(df$date)` and the output is

```
"2016-04-10" 
"2016-04-12" 
"2016-04-12" 
"2016-04-12"
```

I also tried `as.POSIXlt(df$date)` and the output is

```
"2016-04-10 BST" 
"2016-04-12 BST" 
"2016-04-12 BST" 
"2016-04-12 BST"
```

What I am looking for is

```
     date
1    2016-04-10 12:21:25.4278624 
2    2016-04-12 10:01:42.9573987 
3    2016-04-12 10:02:15.2168753 
4    2016-04-12 10:02:45.3005686
```

I also tried the following from the `help`

```
as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 01:30:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

The output is `NA`

How do I get the desired output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me it works like this:

```
test <- "2016-04-10T12:21:25.4278624"
z <- as.POSIXct(test,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")

#output:
z
"2016-04-10 12:21:25 CEST"
```

The code is form here: [converting datetime string to POSIXct date/time format in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667212/converting-datetime-string-to-posixct-date-time-format-in-r)

Answer (score 4):

Another solution would be using the `lubridate` package.

```
 library(lubridate)
 test <- "2016-04-10T12:21:25.4278624"
```

You can use the `ymd_hms` function and don't have to worry about the formats in this case.

```
ymd_hms(test)

#output
[1] "2016-04-10 12:21:25 UTC"
```

You can change the timezone using the `tz` parameter.

```
ymd_hms(test, tz = "EST")
[1] "2016-04-10 12:21:25 EST"
```