# How to convert Hour Minutes character format into a POSIXlt format?

Tags: r, date, strptime, posixlt

Current situation:

```
mydate <- "14:45"

class(mydate)
```

The current class of this value is a character. I would like to convert it into a POSIXlt format.

I tried the strptime() function but it unfortunately adds the full date to my hours when I actually only need Hours:Minutes

```
mydate <- strptime(mydate, format = "%H:%M")
```

What can I do to get a POSIXlt format uniquely containing hours and minutes ?

Thanks in advance for your returns !

Comment: `POSIXlt` always contains the date as well. You can convert it back to character without the date later on but I don't see the point.

Comment: Thnx a lot ! I thought it was possible to get that format only containing hours and minutes

Answer (score 2):

POSIXlt and POSIXct always contain date and time.  You can use chron `times` class to represent times less than 24:00:00.

```
library(chron)

tt <- times(paste(mydate, "00", sep = ":"))
tt
## [1] 14:45:00
```

`times` class objects are represented internally as a fraction of a day so, for example, adding 1/24 will add an hour.

```
tt + 1/24 # add one hour
## [1] 15:45:00
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it works like this:

```
test <- "2016-04-10T12:21:25.4278624"
z <- as.POSIXct(test,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")

#output:
z
"2016-04-10 12:21:25 CEST"
```

The code is form here: [R: convert date from character to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165867/r-convert-date-from-character-to-datetime?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thnx but as said by JBGruber it's not possible to get this format only with hours and minutes

Comment: Yes, JBGruber is right you need to add a date to your string first