# In R, convert string "2021-01-10T01:15:00.000Z" into a datetime

Tags: r, datetime

`2021-01-10T01:15:00.000Z` is a string for the timestamp of 1:15am UTC on 20201/01/10. Currently this is saved as a string, however I need to convert this into a datetime or timestamp type in R. I've tried this

```
as.POSIXct('2021-01-10T01:15:00.000Z', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

...and a bunch of other `format` types, however none work. What is the correct value to pass to 'format' parameter for this to work, or is there a better / different way to do this?

Comment: Try using `anytime`, which drastically simplifies the process of converting _things_ into date time objects!

Comment: `as.POSIXct('2021-01-10T01:15:00.000Z',format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165867/r-convert-date-from-character-to-datetime

Comment: The pattern you tried doesn't match the string. Bot the time separator `T` and the offset specifier `Z` are missing